# SpringBoot + Docker - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I'm trying to Dockerize an existing `maven` SpringBoot project and I cannot get it to start the application in the container. The application works perfectly outside it (with my IDE and with `java -jar target/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`) so I'm not sure what the issue is.

My `Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-11 AS build
WORKDIR /build
COPY src /src
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests

FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim AS runtime    
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /build/target .
CMD ["java" ,"-jar", "app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<!--    <groupId>com.example</groupId>-->
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Backend</name>
    <description>Backend</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <start-class>com.example.Application</start-class>
        <log4jdbc.log4j2.version>1.16</log4jdbc.log4j2.version>
        <rest.assured.version>2.3.3</rest.assured.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!--        Compile -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        -->

        <!--        Runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
            <version>11.5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--        -->

        <!--        Optional -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!--        -->

        <!--        Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>[3.2.2,)</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--        -->

        <!--        Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        -->

        <!--        Utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        Java Table implementation-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>29.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        -->

        <!--        Package to convert words to sentence case -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
            <artifactId>jt400</artifactId>
            <version>10.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        Maths functions for player generation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        -->

        <!--        JSON Stuff -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        -->

        <!--        Implementing and defining cmdline arguments -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.Application</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <!-- select non-aggregate reports -->
                            <report>report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

To build:

```sh
docker build -t app .
```

Which works successfully.

And to run:

```sh
docker run --rm -it -p 8100:8100 app
```

Which throws the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.Application
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:467)
```

I have also tried the [Apache Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html) which did not help me.

To me, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the `Dockerfile`, is there perhaps an issue with the dependencies?

I tried copying the source files into the runtime stage and still no luck.

Comment: Is there a `com.example.Application` in your application/uber jar?

Comment: Does your manifest file say where the main class is? Is `com.example.Application` a default? Another option would be to have your Dockerfile do something like this: `CMD ["java" ,"-cp", "fully-qualified-classname-goes-here"]`

Comment: @aksappy Yes there is

Comment: @jeremyt I don't seem to have a manifest file? It's strange because the application works perfectly without it.

Comment: @Inkblot you might find that when you run it outside of Docker, it works because you only have one main class (i.e. only one `public static void main(String[] args)` method), but I suspect Docker needs to be told which one you want to use?

Comment: @jeremyt How can I tell Docker which one it is? I am getting a java exception after all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> COPY src /src

I am no Docker expert but I am surprised the build doesn't fail there. src is copied on / but "mvn package" runs on /build. I am not sure how this succeeds so maybe I'm wrong but I'd try with a relative path.

Comment: Turns out that was the issue! I changed it to `COPY src src` and the application starts. The build succeeding threw me off I guess, thanks for the help

Comment: Well spotted. A useful tool that I have used is `https://github.com/wagoodman/dive`. Its helpful being able to ensure that not only do the file you WANT get copied to the image, but also its worth checking that files you DON'T want are not copied in error, as this impacts size which impacts upload to Docker Hub, and download to your runtime environment which can impact your service uptime commitments.